# an update statement that adds 100 to a total

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How would I write an update statement that adds 100 to the credit total field of invoices for all invoices that were written the first of the year?

I'm trying to write a statement like:

```
 Update dbo.invoices
 set credittotal (this is the problem right here where i dont know how to     add       100 to this)
 where invoices = (the first of the year)
```

Comment: `set credittotal = credittotal + 100` ?

Comment: Hint: It's exactly how would you normally add 100 to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding 100 means the new value of the column will be the current value plus 100:

```
UPDATE dbo.invoices
SET    credittotal = credittotal + 100
WHERE  DATEPART (dy, invoices) = 1
```